# Rendering a custom bounding box to an image file using python and QGIS?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, pyqt4

Edit: the problem was merely a typo in the coordinates (see comment on definition of `p`). Otherwise the code below should work for other situations, too, if adapted properly. The weird pixelated/grey/colorful images arise, when the rendered coordinates do not lie on the layer extend.

---

I have tried to adopt some code from the [PyQGISDeveloperCookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/pdf/en/QGIS-2.2-PyQGISDeveloperCookbook-en.pdf) (p.37) to render a QGIS raster layer to a png image file (see bottom for layer's metadata). One thing that I have tried to change is to modify the rendered extent to a custom bounding box `bbox` centered in a given point `p`:

```
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QImage, QPainter
    from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize
    import os

    # raster layer in CRS UTM 33N (epsg 25833)
    rlayer = iface.activeLayer()
    # radius for image in meters
    radius = 50
    # center point 
    p = [33401477,5826362] # <- should be 334014.77 for x-coordinate
    # bounding box
    bbox = QgsRectangle(p[0]-radius, p[1]-radius, p[0]+radius, p[1]+radius)
    # image
    img = QImage(QSize(200,200), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
    ## create painter
    painter = QPainter()
    painter.begin(img)
    render = QgsMapRenderer()
    ## set layer set
    lst = [rlayer.id()] 
    render.setLayerSet(lst)
    ## set extent
    render.setExtent(bbox)
    ## set output size
    render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())
    ## do the rendering
    render.render(painter)
    painter.end()
    ## save image
    img.save("D:\\Daten\\QGIStmp\\bbox1.png", "png")
```

The resulting image does not really look the way I expected (though interesting :-)):

[image: bbox1.png]

I tried hard (generating more interesting images), but I couldn't figure out what the problem could be.

---

Querying Layer Metadata:

`>>> rlayer.metadata()`

Response:

```
    u'<p class="glossy">Treiber</p>\n<p>GDAL provider</p>\nECW<br>ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.0)<p class="glossy">Datensatzbeschreibung</p>\n<p>D:/Daten/QGIStmp/Nordost/dop20_400_5826.ecw</p>\n<tr><p>\nCOLORSPACE=RGB</p>\n<p>\nCOMPRESSION_RATE_TARGET=20</p>\n<p>\nVERSION=2</p>\n</tr><p class="glossy">Kanal 1</p>\n<p class="glossy">Kanal 2</p>\n<p class="glossy">Kanal 3</p>\n<p class="glossy">Dimensionen</p>\n<p>X: 10000 Y: 10000 Kan\xe4le: 3</p>\n<p>X : 5000,Y 5000</p><p>X : 2500,Y 2500</p><p>X : 1250,Y 1250</p><p>X : 625,Y 625</p><p>X : 312,Y 312</p><p>X : 156,Y 156</p><p class="glossy">Ursprung</p>\n<p>400000,5.828e+06</p>\n<p class="glossy">Pixelgr\xf6\xdfe</p>\n<p>0.2,-0.2</p>\n<p class="glossy">Leerwert</p>\n<p>*Leerwert nicht gesetzt*</p>\n</p>\n<p class="glossy">Datentyp</p>\n<p>Byte - Acht Bit vorzeichenlose Ganzzahl</p>\n<p class="glossy">Pyramiden\xfcbersichten</p>\n<p><p class="glossy">R\xe4umliches Bezugssystem des Layers</p>\n<p>+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs</p>\n<p class="glossy">Layerausdehnung (in ursp\xfcnglicher Projektion des Layers)</p>\n<p>400000.0000000000000000,5826000.0000000000000000 : 402000.0000000000000000,5828000.0000000000000000</p>\n<p class="glossy">\nKanal</p>\n<p>Kanal 1</p>\n<p>Kanal Nr</p>\n<p>\n1</p>\n<p>Keine Statistik</p>\n<p>\nNoch keine Statistik gesammelt</p>\n<p class="glossy">\nKanal</p>\n<p>Kanal 2</p>\n<p>Kanal Nr</p>\n<p>\n2</p>\n<p>Keine Statistik</p>\n<p>\nNoch keine Statistik gesammelt</p>\n<p class="glossy">\nKanal</p>\n<p>Kanal 3</p>\n<p>Kanal Nr</p>\n<p>\n3</p>\n<p>Keine Statistik</p>\n<p>\nNoch keine Statistik gesammelt</p>\n'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is ok, but there is probably a typo in the `p` list. The first item value seems too big for the location you are working on (I generally work using CRS UTM 32N): probably the last digits of `33401477` are decimals.

If I use other values for `p`:

```
p = [318333,4993348]
```

on this sample raster (CRS UTM 32N, `EPSG:32632`):

[image]

I get a result without any problem (I don't know if it is the desired result).

[image]

Comment: That's it. Thanks for the sharp look! (I was beginning to dive into the QGIS-API, which keeps things rather brief in many places. So this really saved me a lot of time!)

Comment: @Leolo I'm glad it worked also for you and, actually, you wrote a very good code for a beginner!

Comment: As I said, I mainly copied it from the "Cookbook"...